# Function GetDriveTypeW always returns DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR

Tags: c++, winapi

As title says, standard Windows [GetDriveTypeW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) returns value 1 (DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR) for all passed paths.

Documentation says

> The root path is invalid; for example, there is no volume mounted at
> the specified path.

Although I'm pretty sure the supplied paths (e.g. "C:\\temp", "c:\\temp") is valid and is fixed drive (hard disk).

Am I missing something? What could possibly cause this? Any help would be appreciated - I'm not very familiar with WinAPI.

```
bool FileAttributesRetriever::IsExternalPath(const std::filesystem::path& path)
{
    uint32_t driveType = GetDriveTypeW(path.wstring().c_str()); // Always 1 / DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR

    switch (driveType)
    {
        case DRIVE_REMOTE:      // Network storage.
        case DRIVE_REMOVABLE:   // External drive.
        {
            return true;
        }
        default:
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation also says that the argument must be:

> The root directory for the drive.
> A trailing backslash is required...

That is you should call it with `C:\` if you want to check the C: drive, or `C:\temp\` if you want to check the drive mounted at `C:\temp`.

Comment: And don't forget the escape slashes if you're hard-coding in a string literal.

Comment: Or use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).